# Salesforce Triggering an External Procedure

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I'm not 100% sure of the terminology on how to describe what I'm looking to do, so I apologize in advance.

I have a custom entry page for an object in salesforce, and I'm curious as to whether or not it's possible to call an external website when I click the save button.

Rough Example:

1. User enters in a new Account and hits save.
2. After saving the Account, The extender class calls to a webpage that inserts an entry into an external database to let a different set of users external to salesforce know that something new has been created.

Again, I apologize. I know I'm not describing this very well. Thank you for any and all input!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  Take a look at the [Invoking Callouts Using Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_callouts.htm) section of the Apex Code Developer's Guide.  Salesforce refers to this (your Apex code connecting to another web server) as an HTTP Callout.

Also, take a look at [questions with the "callout" tag](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/callout) on the [dedicated StackExchange site for Salesforce.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This page seems to have moved to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_http.htm